# Failing to turn queryset into JSON with a many2many model

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-queryset

I want to serialize a simple queryset but I am failing. I have a model that has a many to many relationship and I want to display only some fields.

My models:

```
class BuildingGroup(models.Model):
    description           = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    buildings             = models.ManyToManyField(Building, default=None, blank=True)



class Building(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    year_of_construction = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

This is what I am doing in my view:

```
class DetailBuildingGroupView(StaffRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = BuildingGroup
    context_object_name = 'group'
    queryset = BuildingGroup.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        id = self.kwargs.get("id")
        return get_object_or_404(BuildingGroup, id=id)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailBuildingGroupView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        bg = BuildingGroup.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs.get('id'))

        arr = []
        for item in bg:
            x = item.buildings.values('name', 'net_leased_area')
            arr.append(x)

        context['buildings'] = arr

        return context
```

this gives me back a queryset like this:

```
[<QuerySet [{'name': 'TestBuilding', 'net_leased_area': 1234.0}, {'name': 'Another test building', 'net_leased_area': 2242.0}, {'name': 'Crazy new item', 'net_leased_area': 12.0}]>]
```

this is almost what I want. But now I am trying to turn it into JSON format.

I tried various ways like:

```
data = json.loads(serializers.serialize("json", arr))
```

or like

```
  result = list(bg.values('name', 'net_leased_area'))
        data = (json.dumps(result))
```

It tells me either that my queryset is not json serializable, or that it has no attribute Meta, or in the last case that it cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. (which makes sense cause I am not looping through anymore.)

I think it is the m2m relation that makes me problems.

I thought I was on the right track but I am no so sure anymore. Can someone help? Thanks very much in advance. Help is very much appreciated.

By the way I think it is weird that when returning `arr`it returns a queryset...

EDIT:

Here is how my data looks like:

```
 {
        "description": "Building Group 1",
        "project": "hb0001",
        "buildings": [
            {
                "name": "TestBuilding",
                "year_of_construction": 1950,
                "net_leased_area": 1234.0,

            },
            {
                "name": "Another test building",
                "year_of_construction": 1234,
                "net_leased_area": 2242.0,

            },
]
```

EDIT 2: I can get the queryset that I want with         `bg = BuildingGroup.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs.get('id')).prefetch_related('buildings')`

But I still can't get my queryset into a JSON....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't yet have enough reputation to comment. So a standalone answer for one line of code.

Now to get the filtered objects in JSON, use `list(object.values())` instead of passing the value arguments.

I assume `bg` is the queryset obtained after filtering through objects which you were passing through context.

```
data = list(bg.values())

filtered_data = [{'name' : item['name'], 'net_leased_area': item['net_leased_area']} for item in data]
```

This filtered data now has the JSON information that you need.

Now you can pass this list through JSON response

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

return JsonResponse(filtered_data, safe=False)
```

Comment: thank you very much Aditya!! Well, if I do this I get a list like that ``` [{'id': 9, 'description': 'Building Group 1', 'project_id': 'hb0001',``` , but I only want a list of my many to many field. That's why I am looping through the array to get my fields.  And this queryset which is in arr = [] I want to turn into JSON....Is that understandable?

Comment: Once you get the items in a list, you can perform operations to get what you need. Let me edit it in the answer itself.

Comment: thank you Aditya, this is very helpful. Yet my problem is that the line ```data = list(bg.values()) ``` doesn't give me back the list that I need. I need a list of my many2many relation. I need a list like ```[{"name", : "testbuilding"; "net_released_area" : 15}].``` Otherwise I get a list like:```[{'id': 9, 'description': 'Building Group 1', 'project_id': 'hb0001'}]..``` That's why I was looping through the queryset in the first place. I added a screenshot of the API data to be more clear

Comment: alos had an error in my question. I want to return the arr, not the bg

Comment: edited again: I can get my queryset with ```bg = BuildingGroup.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs.get('id')).prefetch_related('buildings')
``` But still I am stuck with turning it to JSON

Comment: Solved it like so: ```bg = list((BuildingGroup.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs.get('id')).prefetch_related('buildings').values('buildings__name', 'buildings__net_leased_area')))``` then ```json_data = json.dumps(bg)```

Comment: Aditya, thank you, you got me on the right track, thus I accept your answer